# How can I get a Point from a DevExpress GridControl inside a DoubleClick event Handler?

Tags: c#, parameters, casting, devexpress

I'm working with a `DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` and the double click event in c#.  The event handler signature takes an object and EventArgs as it's parameters:

```
  private void gvHL7_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
     .
     .
     .
  }
```

However, I want to use the .Point property, and EventArgs doesn't have that property.  I know that DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuEventArgs does, but it's saying that's an invalid casting.  What type should I cast my EventArgs instance to if I wish to access the .Point property?

Edit: The double click function I'm working with is provided by devexpress for their grids.

Comment: Do you know what sub class is actually passed into the second parameter?

Comment: The class is System.EventArgs

Comment: EventArgs has no point property and no cast/conversion/magic/voodoo can add a point to EventArgs

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  e contains both an X and Y coordinate, as well as which mouse click was received (right or left).  From those coordinates, there has to be a way to get a point property

Comment: There is no double click function in c# ! Can you explain what you need? Are you working with devexpress `GridControl` and want to handle row doubleclick event?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for not being more clear.  I'm working with a devexpress grid.  I'll make the appropriate edits now.

Comment: so the item firing this event has the `Point` object?

Comment: Still not clear. What you want achieve?

Comment: @SeanSmyth, I edited the question to disambiguate. If the edit conveys your intent, do you mind reopening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but was not able to get a point property.  Instead, I casted EventArgs to MouseEventArgs and passe the coordinates into the function through a .X and a .Y property.

Answer (score 2):

See this example from the [DevExpress Support site](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A2934.aspx). You need to cast the `sender` to get the `Point`.

```
private void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;    
    Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`DoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) event in C# only tells you that a double click occured. If you need the mouse coordinates, you need to either catch the [`MouseClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx) event or use the [`MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) property of the control throwing the event (in this case, `gvHL7.MousePosition` most likely).